# serial port communication

Tags: winapi, serial-port

HI all,

I am doing serial port communication program. How do I achieve the following.

1. Need to know number bytes available for reading.
2. Flushing

Note: I am creating File with Overlapped option.

thanks in advance

~ Johnnie

Comment: You might want to include the language/platform you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to query the number of bytes available first, and then read them. The standard way would be to just allocate a buffer (say 1000 chars), then call ReadComm() which *tells* you how many bytes were actually used (e.g. less than or equal to 1000).

You can flush the buffer of serial io using FlushFileBuffers() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28VS.85%29.aspx) but since you want asynchronous IO, you probably only want to do that when you have written to a file and then *want to move the file* (certainly not on every call to WriteComm()).

More info:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx